# Is this method thread safe?

Tags: java

Are  these methods `getNewId()` & `fetchIdsInReserve()` thread safe ?

```
public final class IdManager {

    private static final int NO_OF_USERIDS_TO_KEEP_IN_RESERVE = 200;

    private static final AtomicInteger regstrdUserIdsCount_Cached = new AtomicInteger(100);
    private static int noOfUserIdsInReserveCurrently = 0;

    public static int getNewId(){                   
          synchronized(IdManager.class){
              if (noOfUserIdsInReserveCurrently <= 20)
                      fetchIdsInReserve();    

              noOfUserIdsInReserveCurrently--;
          }
          return regstrdUserIdsCount_Cached.incrementAndGet();
    }


    private static synchronized void fetchIdsInReserve(){
        int reservedInDBTill = DBCountersReader.readCounterFromDB(....); // read column from DB 

        if (noOfUserIdsInReserveCurrently + regstrdUserIdsCount_Cached.get() != reservedInDBTill) throw new Exception("Unreserved ids alloted by app before reserving from DB");

        if (DBUpdater.incrementCounter(....)) //if write back to DB is successful
              noOfUserIdsInReserveCurrently += NO_OF_USERIDS_TO_KEEP_IN_RESERVE;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the `// fetch from DB here...` code liable to get blocked by other threads?  In particular, other threads that have started doing some DB stuff and *then* want to get a new ID?  If so, you're potentially opening yourself up to deadlocks.

Comment: since the call to that method is just via that synchronized block inside `getNewId()` I belive this method would be called by just one thread at a time right ?

Comment: I'm assuming this is not the only code you have that's ever going to touch a database...other code could be acquiring locks and such too.

Comment: ofcourse I have other methods being called concurrently that execute other DB queries/writes but not anything that would update the data related to this Ids counter in DB.

Comment: Consider: `synchronized(db) { /*do a query;*/  int id = IdManager.getNewId(); /*insert something;*/ }`.  If your "fetch from DB" code also works like that, and another thread is getting an ID at the exact same time, the latter thread will be blocked waiting for the DB to unlock, and the first thread will be blocked waiting for the IdManager lock.  Point being, thread-safety is harder than it looks, and at times it's a rather holistic thing.  If we don't see the "fetch from DB" code, we can't be sure it's not doing something stupid that'll cause deadlocks.

Comment: I added the complete code to the method fetchIdsInReserve(), hopefully it makes the situation more clear now..? Could you please post an answer with solution/hint to any problem/issue you're seeing with this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

If 21 threads comes in here

```
      synchronized(IdManager.class){
          if (noOfUserIdsInReserveCurrently <= 20)
                  fetchIdsInReserve();    

          noOfUserIdsInReserveCurrently--;
      }
```

and wait while another 180 threads proceed through the top and through the line below, then by the time the 21st thread reaches the line below, there will be no user ids in reserve when the 21st thread from the first group calls

```
      return regstrdUserIdsCount_Cached.incrementAndGet();
```

EDIT:

Here's the initial state on class load:

```
regstrdUserIdsCount_Cached = 100
noOfUserIdsInReserveCurrently = 0
```

Let's assume that the write back to the DB is always successful.  If it isn't, this code is clearly broken, because it still allocates an ID in that case.

The first thread comes through, and calls fetch because there are no ids in reserve.

```
regstrdUserIdsCount_Cached = 100
noOfUserIdsInReserveCurrently = 0
```

assuming the DB returns 100 as the initial ID, after the method completes without contention

```
regstrdUserIdsCount_Cached = 101
noOfUserIdsInReserveCurrently = 199
```

Now, let's assume 178 more threads go through without contention

```
regstrdUserIdsCount_Cached = 279
noOfUserIdsInReserveCurrently = 21
```

if that thread is preempted by another that comes through after it exits the `synchronized` block but before it decrements the atomic `int`, the preempting thread will trigger a fetch.

Since `noOfUserIdsInReserveCurrently` has not been decremented by the thread that was pre-empted,

```
(noOfUserIdsInReserveCurrently + regstrdUserIdsCount_Cached.get() != reservedInDBTill)
```

will be false.

Assuming that exception indicates a failure mode, we have a failure during one interleaving that is not thrown during other-interleavings.  Therefore, the code is not thread-safe.

The solution is to consistently access `regstrdUserIdsCount_Cached` inside the critical section.  In that case, it need not be an atomic int, but can simply be a non-`final` int.

Comment: Sorry couldn't really understand your point.. but could you propose a correct solution please ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Doesn't matter how many threads come here. The code inside the synchronized block is executed by one thread at a time.

Comment: @EugeneRetunsky, true, but the code inside the synchronized block checks that there are resources available before the atomic integer update.  The atomic integer update which is guarded by that precondition is outside the synchronized block.

Comment: The atomic integer is just a counter which increases. Doesn't matter where it is.

Comment: @EugeneRetunsky, no it's not.  See the `throws` clause in the fetch method.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: I couldn't completely understand, but that `AtomicInteger` object `regstrdUserIdsCount_Cached` is just a counter.. The throws clause in the fetch method was just intended to notify me in case there is something wrong going anyhow.

Comment: & as far as I understand that synchronized block will allow access only to one thread at a time & after it has guaranteed an id to a thread from reserve it is safely allotted to it via the AtomicInteger object. And incase you are referring to any problem inside fetch method that that too is also accessible by atmost one thread at a time.. Anyways could you kindly propose how to correct the defect you're seeing ? Thanks so much!

Comment: @EugeneRetunsky, Please see my edit.  It explains a failure mode that is triggered during one set of possible interleavings that does not occur during other interleavings.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: Indeed you're correct. Got your point  now. Sorry for the confusions & thanks for such a closer look!!

Comment: @MikeSamuel: another thing that I wanted to confirm, When I `synchronize(IdManager.class)`, does it prevent any other thread from accessing *any other synchronized static methods for that class* or just that block itself ? Incase of former that could lead to a deadlock, since fetch method is also synchronized,  right?

Comment: At most one thread can be inside a `synchronized (obj)` for a given `obj`.  So `synchronized (Foo.class)` prevents any thread from entering that block while another thread is in a `static synchronized` method for that class or in `synchronized (Foo.class)` block.

Answer (score 1):

You the field `noOfUserIdsInReserveCurrently` is not accessed from anywhere else, then yes - access to it is thread-safe.

P.S. if `fetchIdsInReserve` is called only from inside the synchronized
 block in the `getNewId` method, then you don't have to make the method synchronized.

UPDATE: as long as the question was edited, now it is not thread-safe. You have to have the return statement in the first method INSIDE the synchronized block. And it doesn't have to be an AtomicInteger, it can be just a simple `int` in this case.

Comment: `noOfUserIdsInReserveCurrently` is also accessed inside the `fetchIdsInReserve()` where it is incremented, but I believe this also behaves as synchronized since it was invoked from a synchronized block right?

Comment: Right. If the field accessed ONLY from inside synchronized(IdManager.class) blocks, or static synchronized method of this class - it's thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example test to show it is thread safe. Replace the AtomicInteger with an int and get rid of the syncs and the test should fail.

```
public static void main(String... arg) throws Exception {
final int loops = 1042;
for (int l = 0; l != loops; l++) {
  reset(); // add this method to your class to reset the counters
  final int maxThreads = 113;
  final ArrayList<String> checker = new ArrayList<String>();
  final CountDownLatch cl1 = new CountDownLatch(maxThreads);
  final CountDownLatch cl2 = new CountDownLatch(maxThreads);
  for (int x = 0; x != maxThreads; x++) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        cl1.countDown();
        try {
          cl1.await(); // stack all threads here
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int id = getNewId();
        synchronized(checker) {
          checker.add("" + id);
        }
        cl2.countDown();
      }
    });
    thread.start();
  }
  cl2.await();
  for (int x = 0; x != maxThreads; x++) {
    String key = "" + (101 + x); // 1st ID value
    if (!checker.contains(key)) {
      System.out.println("Checker 1 FAIL - missing id=" + key);
    } else {
      checker.remove(key);
      if (checker.contains(key)) {
        System.out.println("Checker 2 FAIL - extra id=" + key);
      }
    }
  }
  for (int x = 0; x != checker.size(); x++) {
    String key = "" + (101 + x);
    System.out.println("Checker 3 FAIL - extra id=" + key);
  }
}
}
```

Comment: You can't mechanically prove correctness; you can only show the presence of bugs, or that specific situations don't cause the bug to manifest itself.  Threading bugs are particularly non-deterministic, and thus prone to evade every attempt at detection until the moment when they can cause the most damage.  :)